# ${1\over{n+1}} {2n \choose n} = {2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need to prove that $${1\over{n+1}} {2n \choose n} = {2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-1}$$

I started by writing out all the terms using the formula ${n!\over{k!(n-k)!}}$ but I can't make the two sides equal.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: CillianR: Do you know about accepting answers to questions you ask? We encourage users to accept one answer per question asked, if one is found to be helpful. To accept an answer, just click on the grey $\Large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it. And you receive two reputation points for each answer you accept. You can accept only one answer per question, but you can upvote as many answers as you find to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ {2n \choose n}-{1\over{n+1}} {2n \choose n}$$

$$=\binom{2n}n\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{(2n)!}{n! n!}\cdot\frac n{n+1}$$
$$=\frac{2n!}{\{(n+1)\cdot n!\}\{n\cdot(n-1)!\}}\cdot n$$

$$=\frac{2n!}{(n+1)!\cdot (n-1)!}$$

$$ = {2n \choose n-1}= {2n \choose n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $(n+1)! = (n+1)n!$ and $n! = n(n-1)!$, we have
$$
\binom{2n}{n-1} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!} = \frac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
$$
and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Note that $$ \begin {align*} \dbinom {2n}{n-1} &= \dfrac {(2n)!}{(n-1)! (n+1)!} \\&= \dfrac {n}{n+2} \cdot \dfrac {(2n!)}{n!n!} \\&= \dfrac {n}{n+1} \cdot \dbinom {2n}{n}, \end {align*} $$ so we have: $ \dbinom {2n}{n-1} = \left( 1 - \dfrac {1}{n+1} \right) \cdot \dbinom {2n}{n}, $ which is equivalent to what we wanted to show.

It seems I've been beaten by 2 answers . . .

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $n+1$. On RHS you get $\binom{2n}{n}(n-n+1)$ which will be equal to LHS. This is because 
$$
\binom{2n}{n-1}\cdot (n+1)=\binom{2n}{n-1}\cdot (n+1)\cdot \frac{n}{n}=n \cdot \binom{2n}{n}
$$